# Flutter chewie slow with large videos

Tags: flutter

now I'm making a videos app using flutter and chewie
all my videos get from Server through API based on Laravel. but all videos has large size for example 500MB, 600MB, or 700MB. the problem is when play the video it playing very slowly. although internet speed in fine.

How i can solve this issue ?

Comment: hi ! did you find any solution? I am facing the same issues. It takes lots of time to just load the initial frames of the video.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, Did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, have you got any solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution